# Как при верстке сайта выставить расположение элементов один за другим?

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Пытаюсь сделать на bootstrap(e). Есть контейнер с фоном в котором 3 ряда в которых лежат логотипы, кнопка, и группа кнопок. Под ними нужно расположить еще и меню например [стандартный navbar](http://bootstrap-3.ru/components.php#navbar) так что бы он привязывался к предведущему элементу и при уменьшении разширения экрана(и связаног с этим уменьшения высоты фонового изображения которое) не сказал как попало. ЗЫ поверх всего этого безобразия еще будет вешатся js который будет менять высоту хедера уменьшая его при прокрутке страницы вниз.

Подскажите как правильно нужно позиционировать элементы что бы этот стандартный navbar "прилипал" к элементу расположеному выше и не независил от высоты этого элемента?

Вот так выглядит без margin(ов) на нормальм экране
[image: Вот так выглядит без margin(ов) на нормальм экране]
Вот так выглядит на мобильных устройствах
[image: Вот так выглядит на мобильных устройствах]

Как то так должно позиционироватся относительно на всех экранах
[image: Как то так должно позиционироватся относительно на всех экранах]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в стилях. Для элемента с фоном было установленно:

```css
background-image: url(images/header.jpg);

background-attachment: fixed;

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: contain;
```

А для контейнера в котором лежат элементы, в том числе и фон была задана высота:

```css
height: ##px
```

При выставлении background-repeat: no-repeat и background-size: contain; нельзя дополнительно задавать размер контейнера в котором это все будет лежать иначе при изменении страницы меняется размер хедера и как следствие создается пустое пространство. Единственное, чего я не понимаю так это почему при указании background-size: contain фоновое изображение все таки не занимает весь предоставленный ей контейнер.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите у элемента параметр `display: inline` или `display: inline-block`

Comment: У меня в html была ошибка и не был закрыт div.container в котором лежит весь хедер перед меню. После этого элемент меню располагается правильно(под контейнером с картинкой), но результат исправления все равно не удовлетворительный: у фона стоят атрибуты:background-repeat: no-repeat  и  background-size: contain; в результате картинка вжимается по высоте и не заполняет контейнер полностью из за чего и возникает пустое место над меню